# iFrame links to open in new window

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

I have the following iframe in my html page.

```
<iframe src="www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Is it possible to force all anchor  links within the iframe to open in a new window (without using jquery/javascipt)? Note that I do not have control over iframe source content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

This isn't possible with JavaScript either.

It is not your site. You cannot control what the links do.